# Facebook JS SDK API not authorizing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following JS function:

```
<pre><code>
function fblogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if ( response.status === 'connected' ) {
                objFacebookUser.token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    objFacebookUser.id = response.id;
                    connect( objFacebookUser );
                });
            } else if( response.status === 'not_authorized' ){
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize!');
            } else {
                console.log('User is not logged in!');  
            }
        }, {scope:'{{$smarty.const.FACEBOOK_CONNECT_PERMS}}'});
    }
</code></pre>
```

I have never had any problems with this until today. For some reason, one account I'm trying to use Facebook connect on will always throw "not_authorized" as the response.

I tried deleting the app from that account's applications. It would request to Allow permissions, I click allow and it throws "not_authorized" again. I'm totally stuck. Been reading on this for the whole day now without a solution. This doesn't happen to every account, but I need to get to the bottom of this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Armin, Please try to add your app scope permission directly instead of your  {scope:'{{$smarty.const.FACEBOOK_CONNECT_PERMS}}'}); Lets try to fix it by trail and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

I was in Sandbox enabled mode. Make sure that Sandbox mode is DISABLED. Otherwise, you'll run into a lot of authentication issues.

Cheers!
Armin